Washing Sprayed Basil
I had to spray my basil with neem oil(organic) due to beetle infestation. I haven’t previously washed my basil but do now. However want to harvest a good portion to make pesto for freezing. Any suggestions for best/easiest way to go about it?

Since you’ll be making pesto, you won’t have to be gentle with them like if you were decorating a salad or something.

Submerge in a bowl of water, gently swirl, drain and repeat if necessary.  Use a salad spinner to remove as much water as possible.  Make pesto.
